# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

**Dell XPS 13 9350** Ubuntu 23.04

Recently purchased Dell vintage 2015, came with Win10, did not test BT before installing Ubuntu 22.10 and then shortly after installed Ubuntu 23.04. Both installations went well. 22.10 using a USB stick,  23.10 via Wifi. Overwrote the Win OS.

Blue tooth device icon shown at top of screen in Mate desktop. Have two working BT devices, a mouse, and a keyboard. They both work with my Android. But neither device is shown in the BT 'Devices' screen. Clicking 'Search' doesn't show any devices.

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:6412 Broadcom Corp. BCM2045A0

Assuming it's a Broadcom Bluetooth device, this listing doesn't show it.

A rfkill list shows:

2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

I've downloaded several driver packages that Dell shows for Linux and tried to install them with no change. The Bluetooth hardware doesn't show any devices.

Anyone know how to deal with this? Thanks.

**Edit** I have gotten Bluetooth to display a couple BT devices, neither one of them are mine. Don't know where they are coming from. Cannot attach to them and they fade from the Device page. They just sorta show up occasionally, won't let me attach, then fade away.

man -k bluetooth
blueman-applet (1)   - a tray applet for managing bluetooth
blueman-manager (1)  - bluetooth device manager
blueman-sendto (1)   - application for sending files to bluetooth devices
blueman-services (1) - Configure local bluetooth services
bluetooth (1)        - enable/disable internal bluetooth device
bluetooth-sendto (1) - GTK application for transferring files over Bluetooth
bluetoothctl (1)     - interactive bluetooth control tool
bluetoothd (8)       - Bluetooth daemon
btmon (1)            - Bluetooth monitor
ciptool (1)          - Bluetooth Common ISDN Access Profile (CIP)
gatttool (1)         - tool for Bluetooth Low Energy device
hciconfig (1)        - Configure Bluetooth devices
hcitool (1)          - Configure Bluetooth connections
hex2hcd (1)          - Broadcom Bluetooth firmware converter
hid2hci (1)          - Bluetooth HID to HCI mode switching utility
mpris-proxy (1)      - Bluetooth mpris-proxy

jimtek@jimtek-XPS-13-9350:~$ id
uid=1000(jimtek) gid=1000(jimtek) groups=1000(jimtek),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)

jimtek@jimtek-XPS-13-9350:~$ ls -l /dev/blue*
ls: cannot access '/dev/blue*': No such file or directory

Comment: You can get some information by watching the boot-time logs, as your system discovers it's hardware with: `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Also `service bluetoothd status`. Also `man -k bluetooth`.

Comment: Look at the "group" of the Bluetooth device: `ls -l /dev/blue*`. Is that group among your "additional groups"? `id` to see. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -t bluetoothd`

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed all available solutions and even after that Bluetooth is not working,then try following steps. It worked for me :)

1. Go to : https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware
2. Download zip
3. Extract the zip file
4. from terminal hit : `sudo mv /lib/firmware/brcm /lib/firmware/old_brcm`

> What this will do is basically rename the ***brcm*** folder present in location : ****/lib/firmware/**** to ***old_brcm***

5. After that just move brcm folder from the extracted zip to ***/lib/firmware/brcm***

   `mv /Downloads/{extracted_zip_folder_name}/brcm  /lib/firmware/brcm`

### And boom

restart your machine :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. It hasn't been a problem because the Dell is my traveling computer and hasn't been used much. I'll try out your solution and let you know if it works...

Comment: Well, that worked to give me working BT, but it trashed my Wifi. I no longer get Wifi and I used Wifi to download that zip file. After reboot, wifi is dead. Now what?

Comment: Well it worked for me pretty well. If it isn't working on your end you can undo the process.
1. Delete the current brcm folder
2. rename old_brcm to brcm
& restart your machine.

Comment: I restored my Wifi. So back to BT not working.